# The upper Darboux sum of a function $f$

Tags: analysis, riemann-sum

I am supposed to find the upper Darboux sum of a function $f$, where:

Let $D$ be a partition of the interval $$\left [ 0,1 \right ] $$ in five intervals of equal length and the function $f$ be 
$$
f(x)=kx,\text{ where }k<0.
$$ What is the upper Darboux sum of $f$ respect to the partition $D$?

I know that the upper Darboux sum of $f$ with respect to $D$ is defined as:
$$
U_{f,D}=\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})M(f,\left [ x_{i-1},x_{i} \right ]) 
$$
and I know that the length of my interval is 0.2, but I do not understand the part with supremum, or how exactly I should do it.

Comment: do you know something else about the interval $(a,b)$? like, if $a,b$ are negative, positive, etc...

Comment: @friedvir Interval is $$\left [ 0,1 \right ] $$, so when I divide it into five partions the length is 0.2

Comment: O.k, so you know that in each partition, the left-most point will give you the highest value (because the function goes down), so you take those points and get the upper Daroux sum.

Comment: @friedvir okay, thanks you, so the result will be 0.4k